# Shell: How to open a file and erase the content inside

Tags: shell

I have installed a log software called Fluentd on my server that comes with a conf file in /etc/td-agent/td-agent.conf. This file is full of sentences and examples, a so called "standard configuration". I want to make a shell script that erases all the content in the file and then adds this:

```
{   echo "include /home/adrian/app/config/fluentd/td-agent.conf"  } >> /etc/td-agent/td-agent.conf
```

But before adding this I need to erase the content of the file (not the file itself).
I dont know how to open /etc/td-agent/td-agent.conf and erase all the content. How do you do this in shell?

Best, Adrian

PD: Im working as root on a centos.

Comment: Just use > instead of >>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo "include /home/adrian/app/config/fluentd/td-agent.conf" > /etc/td-agent/td-agent.conf
```

Note the use of `>` rather than `>>`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to leave existing code alone, redirecting from nothing will truncate the file.

```
> /etc/td-agent/td-agent.conf
```

Comment: don't you mean `cat /dev/null > /etc/td-agent/td-agent.conf`? With your command my shell is waiting for more input.

Comment: @Miles: Which shell are you using that doesn't understand null redirection?

Comment: I'm using zsh. Should my shell assume that redirecting from nothing is the same as from /dev/null?

Comment: @MilesYucht: Bash opens the file for writing, truncating it in the process, and then immediately closes it since nothing runs. I suppose zsh does it differently.

Comment: You're absolutely right; I've never noticed that before. Zsh then reads from standard input, so `> myfile` followed by `CTRL-D` achieves the exact same effect.